# Index error in python using modules os and sys

Tags: python

I have been given an exercise to show the name of a file in a directory, and to stop it from crashing when the path is nonexistent.
This is my code:

```
import sys
import os

PATH = 1


def main():
    try:
        os.path.exists(sys.argv[PATH])
    except os.error and sys.stderr:
        print "Error - no such path"
    directory = sys.argv[PATH]
    print os.listdir(directory)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I keep getting error messages that say that my list index is out of range. What should I do? .

Also, I am new to python so please don't go too far.

Comment: `os.error` and `sys.stderr` are not the right errors to `except` for.

Comment: what should I do to fix the code???

Comment: If you call the script with no arguments, `sys.argv[1]` is going to raise an `IndexError` ...

Comment: What sort of error is being raised? Perhaps an `IndexError`? Then why are you `except`ing `os.error` or `sys.stderr`? (Are these even valid exception classes?)

Comment: @SeanPianka I'm not sure why, but `os.error` is a subclass of `Exception`. However, `sys.stderr` is not (In Python 3 at least)

Comment: Do you know what an `IndexError` is? If not, perhaps you should start googling.

Comment: it is an IndexError, what error should I except
BTW these are valid exception classes

Comment: I do know what an IndexError is, but I do not know how to solve this prob.

Comment: I think you need to understand the question at heart.  It is giving you an index error because when you called this in the cmd line, you didnt supply the next variable.  Im not sure what you are trying to do, but if the minimum set is not met then it should exit.  I usually use the "args" utility to create a cmd line arg parser.  That ultimately depends on the use case.  It might not be needed as it could be overkill

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some changes to catch all the exceptions and reformatted for python 3.

- Moved all the commands that may error out to a try block
- Changed the exception handler to `BaseException` per python 3 error recommendation
- Added Handler for IndexError
- Added more print information about the caught exception

I hope this helps.

```html
import sys
import os

PATH = 1


def main():
    try:
        os.path.exists(sys.argv[PATH])
        directory = sys.argv[PATH]
        print(os.listdir(directory))

    except BaseException as base_error:
        print("Error - no such path --> ", base_error)

    except IndexError as index_error:
        print("Path is not an index --> ", index_error)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: It's important to remember that that this may or may not solve your overall exercise. I reformatted for readability and to set you up to catch the exceptions so that you can further troubleshoot your script. Good luck on the assignment.

Comment: yeah, sure. just tested it again

Answer (score 0):

`sys.argv` is similar in nature to C's argv. The first element (at index 0) is the name of the script being called. The remaining elements, including the one that you're trying to access, are the elements that you *pass* to the script. For example, say your code is in a file called test.py, and in your shell you execute:

```
test.py abc
```

Then `sys.argv[1]` would be `abc`. You have `PATH = 1`, so you're trying to access the second element of the `sys.argv` array. If you just do `test.py`, then the index will go out of bounds on the `sys.argv` array.

You have some other problems (like trying to catch things that aren't exceptions), so I'm not sure how you even get to the index error. If you replace the invalid `except os.error and sys.stderr:` with `except:`,  the script will then throw an index error if you invoke it as `test.py` instead of something like `test.py path/to/the/file.txt`.